# Positioning header for only mobile version of blog pages?

Tags: mobile, header, css-position, positioning, custom-wordpress-pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLju1.png)

Here's the issue, I need to add a custom css that only affects mobile version of blog pages but I couldn't figure it out and cannot find a clue in Google either.

I'm trying to adjust the position of header only for mobile version of blog pages.